# Problems when using Autodesk Viewer on iOS 15 device

Tags: ios, autodesk-forge

I'm integrating the Autodesk Viewer in an iOS application.

For that I am using an WKWebView to load the local HTML and javascript to load files from Forge and display them in the web view. Everything is working nice on iOS 15, but for one BIM file, I'm having an issue when loading it into the viewer (I'm using the last 7.x version).
During all the loading we have the BIM plan but at the end the view display a blank view.

Device:

```
iPhone 15.4.1
```

The logs:

```
 JS log: THREE.WebGLRenderer, 71
 JS log: WebGL Renderer: Apple GPU
 JS log: WebGL Vendor: Apple Inc.
⚠️ JS warning: THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc extension not supported.
 JS log: Total geometry size: 31.443790435791016 MB
 JS log: Number of meshes: 7056
 JS log: Num Meshes on GPU: 2550
 JS log: Net GPU geom memory used: 11263334
2022-04-29 10:11:15.769247+0200 [Process] 0x129003950 - [PID=16716] WebProcessProxy::didClose: (web process 0 crash)
2022-04-29 10:11:15.769774+0200 [Process] 0x129003950 - [PID=16716] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=4
2022-04-29 10:11:15.770211+0200 [ProcessSuspension] 0x1280041e0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process because PID 0 is invalid
2022-04-29 10:11:15.770889+0200 [Process] 0x140082018 - [pageProxyID=29, webPageID=30, PID=16716] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 16716), reason 4
2022-04-29 10:11:15.777153+0200 [ProcessSuspension] 0x1280041e0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=0, error: (null)
2022-04-29 10:11:15.783852+0200 [Loading] 0x140082018 - [pageProxyID=29, webPageID=30, PID=16716] WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason=Crash
2022-04-29 10:11:15.795502+0200 [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
2022-04-29 10:11:15.795597+0200 [ProcessSuspension] 0x128004240 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=16716, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
```

Working fine on iPhone 14.5 with the viewer v6.x

Regards,

Comment: We are investigating it

Comment: Hello @AugustoGoncalves, do you have some update about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @T0m_Twt the next minor version (7.68) should have some fixes, I'll share here once it's live in production

Answer (score 0):

Version `7.68` has a fix:

> Fixed: Tab to freeze or reload on IOS 15 devices when loading large models, [more info](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/)

There is still an open issue with WebKit to be addressed.